# rails respond_with associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, grails-controller, respond-with

for example, there's a `Question` model that `has_many :answers`

I'd like to show a form for new answer on the `questions#show` ( just like stackoverflow does )

routes would be something like:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

What is the best way to show the errors for an invalid record under these circumstances?

The problem is that I can't `render` an action I need from within `AnswersController` ( since it would be `questions#show` ), the only way seem to be `redirect_to` and store errors in `flash` hash.

It just looks like a pretty much common scenario, I believe there should be some better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be one of a few cases where it's actually justified to add a new resourceful member route to your `QuestionsController`:

```
resources :questions do
  post 'answer', :on => :member
end
```

which would recognize `question/:id/answer` with a POST request routed to `questions#answer`, allowing you keep all the logic in one controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def answer
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])

    @answer = @question.answers.build(params[:question][:answer])

    if @answer.save
      # show question with newly posted answer at url /question/:id
      redirect_to @question
    else
      # show question with invalid editable answer at url /question/:id/answer
      render 'show'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Explanation: In my opinion, the decision to handle the logic in one controller as opposed to two comes down to what you consider to be the resource of interest. Normally, you would consider each model to represent a distinct resource and thus create a separate controller to handle actions related to each resource. However, when there are multiple deeply coupled models for which multiple actions (e.g. `show`, `new`, `create`) are handled in a single view, it might be cleaner to think of the models as forming a *single* resource.

In this example, I think of the resource as a collective one consisting of *both* the question and its answers. Since this collective resource is uniquely identified by the question itself, I would let the question controller handle it. The `show` action in the questions controller already involves retrieving the collective question-answers resource, so you might think of the `answer` action (and potentially `unanswer` and `reanswer` actions) as the analogue of `update` to that collective resource.

Thinking of the resources this way is largely a matter of design preference, and there will be trade-offs depending on the requirements.

Comment: can't award yet, 30 minutes left

Comment: I don't agree. The creation of an answer belong in `AnswersController#create`. Why is this justified according to you? It's not like it's impossible to render a specific template if there's an error.

Comment: @Mischa See my explanation above.

Comment: I agree with what `cdesrosiers` says since it feels pretty much natural for me too, I even had an `answer_with` method defined for my `question` model before posted this. Still just a matter of personal preference, of course. Another thing I like about this approach is that it allows you to simply use `respond_with @question`

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanation. I see what you mean now. Just like "update a question" you can "answer a question". Answer is a verb, not a noun.

Answer (score 1):

You can render `questions#show` from the `AnswersController` like this:

```
render :template => 'questions/show'
```

If you want to jump to a specific anchor on the page, you have to define that in your answer form:

```
<%= form_for(@answer, :url => question_answers_url(@question, :anchor => 'answer_form')) do |f| -%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a partial which has the form which posts data to the answers_controller#create action.

So, in your questions#show page - show.html.erb, render a partial

```
<%= render :partial => "answers/answer_form" %>
```

In the _answer_form.html.erb, have a form which will post data to answers#create

```
<% form_for @answer do |f| %>
  # have a text area
<% end %>
```

**As far as the flash is concerned**

In the AsnwersController

```
def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @answer = Answer.build(params)
  if @answer.save
    flash[:notice] = "Answer was posted successfully"  
  else
    flash[:error] = "There were a few errors please try again"  
  end
  redirect_to question_path(@question) 
end
```

Comment: It's bad idea to use the flash for errors, besides you cannot repopulate the fields with this solution. Do you want to user to fill out the whole form again if an error occurs?